# Google compute engine IP ranges

Tags: google-compute-engine, google

I'm trying to figure out what the IP ranges for google compute engine are.

I have a library that is locked for use on certain IP ranges.  Crazy I know, it's a bit special.

I hunted around the google document ion but couldn't find a list.
Is there a way of looking this up or querying for it somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408818/what-are-the-ip-ranges-for-gce-zones

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408818/what-are-the-ip-ranges-for-gce-zones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer says, Google describes how to get the list here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_product_name_short_ip_ranges

I found a good script here for following spf records:

https://aplawrence.com/Kerio/recursive_spf.html

create the file lookup.perl as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$domain=shift @ARGV;
@results=getit($domain);


sub getit {
  my $domain=shift;

  my @foo=`nslookup -q=TXT $domain`;
  my @results=();
  foreach (@foo) {
   next if not /$domain\ttext/;
   s/$domain\ttext = "v=spf1//;
   @results=split /\s+/;
   foreach (@results) {
    next if /-all/;
    print "$_\n";
    if (/include:/) {
     s/include://;
     getit($_);
    }
   } 
  } 
}
```

then run:
./lookup.perl _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com | grep ip4

```
ip4:35.190.224.0/20
ip4:35.232.0.0/15
ip4:35.234.0.0/16
ip4:35.235.0.0/17
ip4:35.235.192.0/20
ip4:35.236.0.0/14
ip4:35.240.0.0/15
ip4:35.203.232.0/21
ip4:130.211.4.0/22
ip4:35.220.0.0/14
ip4:35.242.0.0/15
ip4:35.244.0.0/14
ip4:34.64.0.0/11
ip4:34.96.0.0/14
ip4:34.100.0.0/18
ip4:34.100.64.0/19
ip4:108.170.216.0/22
ip4:108.170.220.0/23
ip4:108.170.222.0/24
ip4:35.224.0.0/13
ip4:35.202.0.0/16
ip4:35.190.240.0/22
ip4:35.190.242.0/23
ip4:35.206.0.0/15
ip4:8.34.208.0/20
ip4:8.35.192.0/21
ip4:8.35.200.0/23
ip4:108.59.80.0/20
ip4:108.170.192.0/20
ip4:108.170.208.0/21
ip4:162.216.148.0/22
ip4:162.222.176.0/21
ip4:173.255.112.0/20
ip4:192.158.28.0/22
ip4:199.192.112.0/22
ip4:199.223.232.0/22
ip4:199.223.236.0/23
ip4:23.236.48.0/20
ip4:23.251.128.0/19
ip4:35.204.0.0/14
ip4:35.208.0.0/13
ip4:107.167.160.0/19
ip4:107.178.192.0/18
ip4:146.148.2.0/23
ip4:146.148.4.0/22
ip4:146.148.8.0/21
ip4:146.148.16.0/20
ip4:146.148.32.0/19
ip4:146.148.64.0/18
ip4:35.203.0.0/17
ip4:35.203.128.0/18
ip4:35.203.192.0/19
ip4:35.203.240.0/20
ip4:130.211.8.0/21
ip4:130.211.16.0/20
ip4:130.211.32.0/19
ip4:130.211.64.0/18
ip4:130.211.128.0/17
ip4:104.154.0.0/15
ip4:104.196.0.0/14
ip4:208.68.108.0/23
ip4:35.184.0.0/14
ip4:35.188.0.0/15
ip4:35.216.0.0/15
ip4:35.190.0.0/17
ip4:35.190.128.0/18
ip4:35.190.192.0/19
ip4:35.235.224.0/20
ip4:35.192.0.0/14
ip4:35.196.0.0/15
ip4:35.198.0.0/16
ip4:35.199.0.0/17
ip4:35.199.128.0/18
ip4:35.200.0.0/15
ip4:35.235.216.0/21
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform compute engine IP ranges change over time, that's why I would recommend to use the commands in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range) to have an updated information.

Comment: You should include slightly more information in your answer such that it will remain useful even if the link for whatever reason stops working.

Answer (score 0):

GCP Compute Engine IP ranges are changing over time, however you will be able to check the current IP ranges by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range).

Also, you will be able to check it through the Cloud Shell by running this commands:

```
google_ips=$(for LINE in `dig txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com +short | tr " " "\n" | grep include | cut -f 2 -d :`; do dig txt $LINE +short; done | tr " " "\n" | grep ip4 | cut -f 2 -d : | sort -n | xargs | tr " " ",")

echo $google_ips
```

The commands above will create and an environment variable that contains the current Compute Engine IP ranges.

Moreover, there's an [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/123728158) in order to improve this process.

Hope this helps!